# Dotnet core 3.1 return 401 with status text OK

Tags: angular, api, .net-core, http-error

I can't figure out why my API is returning OK status message for unauthorized call.
Here is my startup config method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger(options => options.RouteTemplate = _swaggerConfigurations.JsonRoute);
                app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint(_swaggerConfigurations.UiEndPoint, _swaggerConfigurations.Name);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>{
                    builder.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
```

Controller action method:

```
[HttpPost(ApiRoutes.Auth.Login)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserToLoginDto dto)
        {
            var loggedInResult = await _authService.Login(dto);
            if (loggedInResult == null)
                return Unauthorized();

            return Ok(loggedInResult);
        }
```

I am using Angular to call this method.
Every time this is returned. 
[image]

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: is this request for get token ?

Comment: @pc_coder yes this request will return token on success, and unauthorized on failure.

Comment: Have you tried with postman  to get token ? I am not sure that token requests includes api prefix.

Comment: @pc_coder Thanks for your time and effort :) actually i have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some code review in detail, I found that I haven't added AddCors() to my services but I am directly using it in the pipeline, also i am using UseHttpsRedirection middleware. My Angular app is running in development mode and there is no SSL. Both the API and Client is running without any certificate. 
After adding AddCors() and removing UseHttpsRedirection middleware, correct HttpErrorResponse is received.

Comment: Running into the same issue.  Mind sharing how you fix it.  I comment out UseHttpsRedirection and enable CORS but still getting 401 where the text is OK.

Comment: @zAnthony what about your client side application? Did you check for SSL?

Comment: ..My angular is running on HTTP and I'm calling the API which runs on HTTPS.  If I was to run the API in HTTP, then I get the Unauthorized statusText. Seems like it was an SSL issue. Thank you.